# Is it possible to control overflow for a jQuery UI Sortable helper?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have markup that looks roughly like this:

```
<div class='root'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='column'>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The root div has `overflow: auto`, and width/height that may change.  The columns have fixed widths and are floated left.  The wrapper has a fixed width corresponding to the sum of the column widths.  The end result is a set of horizontally-laid-out columns within a view that shows scroll bars when the column height or total column width exceeds its bounds.

I have applied a jQuery UI sortable to the wrapper div, so the columns inside can be sorted.  This works great, except for one problem: sortable gives the element being sorted `position: absolute`, which apparently removes it from the normal layout.  So if the column is very tall, the entire page gets a scroll bar until the element is dropped back into position.

Is there any way for the sortable helper to remain contained within the scrolling div even while sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work for you.

You can choose where to append your sortable helper with the following:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ appendTo: 'div.wrapper' });
```

From the docs:

"appendTo: Defines where the helper that moves with the mouse is being appended to during the drag (for example, to resolve overlap/zIndex issues)."